# проблемы с интерпретатором python

Tags: python

установил python 3.7.1 и PyCharm 2018.3.2. все открывается, но при попытке добавить интерпретатор выдает ошибку 'permission denied', а далее нужный интерпретатор и вовсе не отображается в списке

Comment: Попробуйте запустить PyCharm с root правами

Comment: Использовали бы вы Sublime Text или Atom - для начала этого за глаза хватит. А вообще давайте скриншоты и подробнее объясняйте